# Cannot build APK file using Intel XDK (Build 3900)

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk

I created the sample HelloCordova project available in the Intel XDK, but when I build it for Android (using Crosswalk), it is generating a ZIP file instead of an APK file. I did not modify any code/settings of the project (except maybe creating the Android certificate). I even renamed it to APK and copied it to my device to test whether it is actually an APK file or not, but a "Parse Error" message was shown instead on my device.

I even tried to publish it, where we need to select the package (ZIP or APK file created with XDK). But when I select the ZIP file, it says that it is not valid.

The contents of the ZIP file is shown below:
[image]

How can I build an APK file using Intel XDK (Build 3900)?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I clicked on the "Create package", which I thought would create the Android package (APK), but my bad. We have to use PhoneGap build to do that from the ZIP file instead, or rely on the Cloud-based Build System on the XDK - which however will be deprecated soon.